# Telerik RadGridView data comparison with cell formatting

Tags: silverlight, formatting, comparison, telerik-grid, radgridview

I have two RadGridViews in my application. Two Grids are pulling the information from two different sources.  That information bound to grid view.

Both the sources are of same Type `List<MyComplexObject>`. Now I wanted to compare these two grids, and color the cells (to Red) in second grid which has the different value.

How can we implement this functionality using Silverlight, C# and Telerik RadGridView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a Style Selector for the grid you want to have colored in a different way. You would need to prepare a normal cell style and a "Red" cell style as in [this](http://www.telerik.com/help/silverlight/gridview-cell-style-selector.html) example. The article present the complete solution for cell style selector so you will have a full view on how this works. What you would need to do additionaly is to add a property (`DependencyProperty`) to the style selector to which you would bind the data collection against which you check the cell value validity.